# Guava dependencies conflict

Tags: google-classroom

We are developing applications that integrate with Classroom.

One of our application's dependencies attempts to call a newer Guava method that does not exist in the guava-jdk5 Class pulled in by Classroom:

```
com.google.common.collect.Sets.SetView
```

But the method *does* exist in the Guava 22.0, pulled in by the other dependency. Consequently, we hit this exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
```

One of our application's dependencies uses this version of Guava:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The current version of the Classroom API:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-classroom -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-classroom</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev103-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Depends on:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which in turn depends on:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is from Apr 22, 2014.

Essentially, we have a class conflict across differently named jars.

Our questions:

1. From Classroom's perspective, is there a reason we cannot exclude guava-jdk5, in favor quava 22.0?
2. When might Classroom be updating its Guava dependency to a more current version?

Thanks,
ASSISTments Team

Comment: Have you tried visiting the [github post](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild) on how to avoid conflicts using Guava for your build?

Comment: I have now. ;-)  For now we have been excluding guava-jdk5 from the google-api-services-classroom artifact.  If indeed all versions of guava, despite the different artifactIds, are backwards compatible (as that github post seems to imply), then we ought to be ok (excluding guava-jdk5) in favor of guava 22.0.

It would be nice if Classroom updated their own dependency to a newer guava version.

Comment: Did that answer your question?